# the following model the largest content_id

Tags: codeigniter

How to set the following model so that the largest content_id appears ?

```
$this->db->where('content_id', 'the largest content_id');
public function call_last_content()
{

    $this->db->order_by('content_id','asc');
    $this->db->where('content_id', 2);
    $query = $this->db->get('content');
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your function as

```
public function call_last_content()
{

    $this->db->order_by('content_id','DESC');
    $query = $this->db->get('content');
    return $query->row_array(); //returns the row of values of largest content_id as array format
}
```

Then call your model's function and get column values like this..

```
$data = $this->model_name->call_last_content();
$column_name = $data['column_name '];
```